# How do I use FileReader() in Javascript to read 2 different files with different methods

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in HTML, it has 2 file input options.
One is to upload media and one is to upload a .csv file.
I need to take these 2 files read them with the `FileReader()` and pass the results out as a parameter to a function on the server side.

The problem is I need to read them with 2 different methods the media with `reader.readAsDataUrl(file)` and the .csv as `reader.readAsText(file)`.

How can I do this in the same function of the cleint side?

```
function sendCall() {
  var number = document.getElementById('list').files[0]; // I need to read this readerAsText()
  var file = document.getElementById('audio').files[0];
  var name = file.name;
  var reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.onload = function (e) {   
  var content = reader.result;

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(called).makeCall(content, name, number);
 return false;
  } 
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I get it right. But how about just using two instances of `FileReader()`?
Sending one as URL and the other as text. You can send a Cookie ID with the request, so you are able to combine them in the backend. Or some other solution with some kind of ID.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean I;m a bit new to this, would you be able to show sample code with what I provided? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a prototypical example of how to achieve what you want to do.

```js
const sendFiles = (A, B) => {
  console.log({ A, B }); 
}

const readFiles = () => {
  const textFile = document.getElementById('list').files[0];
  const audioFile = document.getElementById('audio').files[0];

  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = ({ target: { result: A } }) => {
    reader.readAsDataURL(audioFile);
    reader.onload = ({ target: { result: B } }) => sendFiles(A, B);
  }

  reader.readAsText(textFile);
}
```

```html
<input type=file id=list /><br>
<input type=file id=audio /><br>
<button onclick=readFiles()>Read</button>
```